# Animating CardWithList CardsLib Android

Tags: java, android, cardslib

I am implementing the `CardWithList` design from `Cardslib` library from Github. Library Link : [Cardslib Github](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)

I want to perform `left in animation` to elements in the list

```
 private void setLeftAdapter() {
        AnimationAdapter animCardArrayAdapter = new SwingLeftInAnimationAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
        animCardArrayAdapter.setAbsListView(mListView);
        mListView.setExternalAdapter(animCardArrayAdapter, mCardArrayAdapter);
    }
```

i dont know where to place this code and there are no  mCardArrayAdapter and mListView in my java code

**GetStat.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardArrayAdapter;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardHeader;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.prototypes.CardWithList;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView;


public class GetStat extends CardWithList {


    long musers;
    long mclicks;
    long mbanner;
    long mptc;
    long mtickets;
    double mwithdraw;
    double mfunds;
    double minvested;
    CommonGateway usersobj, clickobj;

    private void updateResult(String jsonResp) {

        try {

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResp);
            musers = jsonResponse.getLong("users");
            mclicks = jsonResponse.getLong("clicks");
            mbanner = jsonResponse.getLong("banner");
            mptc = jsonResponse.getLong("ptc");
            mtickets = jsonResponse.getLong("tickets");

            mwithdraw = jsonResponse.getDouble("withdraw");
            mfunds = jsonResponse.getDouble("funds");
            minvested = jsonResponse.getDouble("invested");


            CommonGateway usersobj = new CommonGateway(this);

            //Set the value..
            usersobj.SetData("Users", R.drawable.usersico, musers);
            getLinearListAdapter().add(usersobj);
            clickobj.SetData("Clicks", R.drawable.clicks24, mclicks);
            getLinearListAdapter().add(clickobj);




        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public class SimplePoster extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            updateResult(s);


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Webb webb = Webb.create();
            String response = webb.post("http://example.net/api/?action=site_admin&type=json&api=234234df&sub=stats")
                    .ensureSuccess()
                    .asString().getBody();
            return response;
        }
    }

    public GetStat(Context context) {
        super(context);
        new SimplePoster().execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected CardHeader initCardHeader() {
        CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getContext(), R.layout.cardheader);
        //header.setTitle("Statistics");
        return header;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initCard() {
        //Create a CardHeader
        CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getContext());

        //Set the header title
        header.setTitle("Statistics");
        setUseEmptyView(false);
        setUseProgressBar(true);
        updateProgressBar(true, true);

        addCardHeader(header);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ListObject> initChildren() {

        //Init the list
        List<ListObject> mObjects = new ArrayList<ListObject>();
        usersobj = new CommonGateway(this);
        clickobj = new CommonGateway(this);
        bannerobj = new CommonGateway(this);
        fundobj = new CommonGateway(this);
        withdrawobj = new CommonGateway(this);
        ptcobj = new CommonGateway(this);
        ticketsobj = new CommonGateway(this);
        investedobj = new CommonGateway(this);

       /*usersobj.SetData("Users", R.drawable.usersico,musers);
        mObjects.add(usersobj);
*/
        return mObjects;

    }

    @Override
    public View setupChildView(int i, ListObject listObject, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardtitle);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardimage);
        TextView numbers = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardnumbers);

        CommonGateway gatewayObject = (CommonGateway) listObject;
        icon.setImageResource(gatewayObject.icon);
        title.setText(gatewayObject.title);
        numbers.setText(gatewayObject.numbers);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public int getChildLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.cardmain;
    }

    public class CommonGateway extends DefaultListObject {

        String title = "null";
        String numbers = "null";
        int icon = 0;

        public CommonGateway(Card parentCard) {
            super(parentCard);


        }

        public void SetData(String title, int icon, long numbers) {
            this.title = title;
            this.icon = icon;
            this.numbers = String.valueOf(numbers);
        }

        public void SetData(String title, int icon, double numbers) {
            this.title = title;
            this.icon = icon;
            this.numbers = "$" + String.valueOf(numbers);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardArrayAdapter;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    GetStat card;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.action_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("GPT Analytics");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        card= new GetStat(getApplicationContext());
        card.updateProgressBar(false, false);
        card.init();

        //Set card in the cardView
        CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.statcard);

        cardView.setCard(card);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,searchactivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I cant set the progress bar for loading also

Comment: Do you want to animate the item inside the card?

Comment: Yes I want the items inside the list to slide in